# Getting gnome-shell working on nvidia optimus notebook

Tags: unity, 11.10, gnome, nvidia-optimus, gpu

what i need is to enable the lamest hardware acceleration to get gnome-shell or unity 3d working.

- i know about bumblebee/ironhide/bumblebee-project. but i didn't
  understand how to use it directly with x11 server to enable the use
  of those advanced environment.
- i don't care about what card will give me gnome-shell/unity3d working. i wonder if there is a way to use only intel (but accellerated!)
- i really don't care about power save

i'm tired to be reverted to gnome-session-fallback or unity 2d.

please tell me if there is a way or if i will be stuck with gnome 2.* until i'll buy another laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah! I figured out how to get the hardware acceleration of the Intel graphic hd 3000 to enable unity 3d and gnome-shell.

It seems that ubuntu tries to install drivers for both intel hd 3000 and nvidia-optimus card. result? a mess. X11 server can't decide what driver to use and revert to VESA.

So the solution is really simple:

```
apt-get remove --purge nvidia-current nvidia-common nvidia-settings xserver-xorg-video-nv
```

plus remove all other display driver xserver-xorg-video-* except xserver-xorg-video-intel. reboot the computer and tadan! at least you can enjoy a little acceleration!

Answer (score 1):

dude.. this is wrong.. just reinstall the drivers of intel:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel

$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

the problem is that when u remove the nvidia drivers.. the files in 
/usr/lib/xorg/modules/ are removed... but if you reinstall the intel driver it will copy the files back again and everything will be fine! :)

(https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee i am now using bumblebee for using the nvidia card whenever i want, and it works very fine! :D )

if you want to try again to install bumblebee, first we have to remove any old crap you may still have installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove ironhide bumblebee
```

(check out this issue: [I can't uninstall Ironhide, or install any other packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76070/i-cant-uninstall-ironhide-or-install-any-other-packages/95426#95426))

after successfully removing this packages we have to make sure nouveau driver is blacklisted to do that:

we add the text:

```
blacklist nouveau
```

to the file

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

to open the file do

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

now we edit the file:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

We look for the line that says:
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

and we change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash rdblacklist=nouveau"
```

OK! now we have no nouveau anymore :D epic win!! now we have to install the nvidia proprietary drivers

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

(I'm not 100% sure about it, because i installed it using the additional drivers tool!! )

ok, now we have everything set up for installing bumblebee.

first we add the ppa of bumblebee

```
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:mj-casalogic/bumblebee
```

then

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bumblebee
```

after this... we can check if everything is setup by running:

```
$ glxgears
```

this will use the intel HD card... but if you add optirun before the command it will use the nvidia card

$ optirun glxgears

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just another suggestion. I also have an Nvidia card, but Gnome-shell seems to be more responsive with the nouveau driver rather than the official Nvidia one. I actually see a considerable improvement in almost everything Gnome-shell does.

Answer (score 0):

If you constantly use the nouveau driver your battery will drain very fast.

Anyway one more add... if you want to use the nouveau driver instead of the nvidia proprietary you have to edit the file `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` via

```
sudo nano /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
```

and where it says

```
DRIVER="nvidia"
```

change it to:

```
DRIVER="nouveau"
```