# I can't uninstall Ironhide, or install any other packages

Tags: package-management, apt, dpkg, bumblebee

I installed Ironhide (aka BumbleBee). It couldn't get it to work, but now I can't uninstall the package and it's preventing me from installing or removing anything else. Any ideas what I can do to fix this problem?

```
$ sudo apt-get remove -f ironhide
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  virtualgl acpi-call-dkms virtualgl-libs easybashgui
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  ironhide
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 65 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,901 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 297969 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ironhide ...
groupdel: group 'ironhide' does not exist
dpkg: error processing ironhide (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 6
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ironhide
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've fixed this by doing the following:

Edited the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/ironhide.postrm`

Commented out the lines:

```
if [ `cat /etc/group |grep ironhide |wc -l` > 0 ]; then
        groupdel ironhide
fi
```

I was then able to successfully run:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ironhide
```

Answer (score 2):

just add the group like this:

```
sudo addgroup ironhide
```

and then try again to remove ironhide

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove ironhide
```

I will now add an how-to do a right installation of bumblebee here:
[Getting gnome-shell working on nvidia optimus notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67808/getting-gnome-shell-working-on-nvidia-optimus-notebook)