# Intel HD 3000 (Sandy Bridge) 3d games problem

Tags: 11.10, graphics, intel

I can't play any 3d games on Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit because of texture gliches, desktop looks ok but games terrible with Intel HD 3000. Any solution for this?
The laptop is HP 4530s.
exaple Minecraft problem (but it exist in every game) http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/2629/minecraftproblem.png

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/829086) bug is your issue. Buggy intel drivers. There are some very ugly workarounds that I have tried myself that can make the artifacts go away but (in the case of minecraft, at least) do not help the screen flickering.

---

EDIT: Here's the workaround I crafted up. Firstly, you'll need a newer version of intel-gpu-tools to tweak some data. Go [here](https://launchpad.net/~sarvatt/+archive/intel-gpu-tools) to pick up a newer version. You may add the PPA but to avoid a lot of unnecessary updates I recommend just manually downloading the package through "View Package Details", then expand the dropdown entry for the oneiric series and download either the AMD64 or i386 package, depending on whether you have 32 or 64 bit. Install the package.

With this installed, you're going to make a crontab. This will run a command AS ROOT on boot. Run the command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

in the terminal. Type in your password. It will ask you which editor to use. Just pick the default (nano). Scroll down to the bottom and on a new line enter the following:

```
@reboot intel_reg_write 0x9404 0x00001800
```

To save and exit, press control+x, type y, then press enter. Perform a reboot.

From now on the artifacts should no longer be there.

Comment: It would be great. btw. does anybody know if other distros don't have that issue? And will it be fixed in precise (12.04)?

Comment: I'm very confident that it will be fixed. I believe I looked at the upstream reports and the issue seems to be well-known and actively worked on. I think the issue is with all distros as even the latest xorg versions had the issue and people have been actively building newer versions. Any older versions probably just won't work since it's new hardware. (I haven't tried any others out, it's actually not my machine this affected). Sorry about that, it really sucks to be in this position :/. I'll write up my workaround.

Comment: I added my workaround. Be advised that if this doesn't work or isn't good enough for you I would suggest removing the @reboot line from that file. Also, you should make a calendar note of some sort for when you upgrade that machine to 12.04 to remove that line. While it may work fine now there's no telling what keeping an arbitrary command execute like that will do to a future version.

Comment: Thank you! As you said that fixed artifacts but to 100% happiness I had to install optimized driver (http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?50038-Updated-and-Optimized-Ubuntu-Free-Graphics-Drivers).

Comment: Wait, so did following that article completely remove the issues? It says it supports 10.10 and 11.04, not 11.10. Does it work regardless?

Comment: Oh, I have said it too quickly :( I had played Minecraft for 4 minutes and nothing had happened so I decided to wrote that, now I have run it again and artifacts came back very quickly :( Sorry for confusion. I will test HP drivers (http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=5060882&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5060880&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=2020) but only for Suse. Maybe it would help. If not, I will wait for Precise and now use Mac OS X on it...

Comment: In 12.04 (daily) after 10 minutes of playing Minecraft there are no artifacts, but triangles still exist.

Answer (score 1):

Iam currently using Ubuntu 12.04 and had the same problem. Here is what i do:

Install mesa 3d graphic library(I think this was the command, correct me if not)

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Then install this library that lets mesa use texture compression

```
sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0
```

No extra ppa needed. I test it with Amnesia an Minecraft and both work perfectly.

Comment: Both packages were already installed in Ubuntu 12.10 and I still have flickering when playing Amnesia.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure is that bug? I believe that you have this issue:

The problem is that when you remove the Nvidia drivers, the files in `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/` are removed. But if you reinstall the intel driver it will copy the files back again and everything will be fine! Run these commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Check it out [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67808/getting-gnome-shell-working-on-nvidia-optimus-notebook/95437#95437).