# How do I get screen brightness controls to work with Intel HD3000 graphics?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, intel-graphics

### TL;DR Version

I'm looking for a simple way to install a working graphics driver for my laptop (via command line or system settings) so that I can control the brightness and resolution.

### Solution

Upgraded to 12.04 and followed instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/126549/46766. No special driver needed.

---

### Additional Detail

I have an [HP Pavilion g7-1310us](http://www.shopping.hp.com/en_US/home-office/-/products/Laptops/HP-Pavilion/A6Z19UA?HP-Pavilion-g7-1310us-Notebook-PC&&rwCatalog=-&rwCategory=-) laptop with this integrated graphics processor I bought a few months ago. [I have installed Ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105651/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-on-an-hp-pavilion-g7-not). But I have never got the display working properly. Some specific symptoms:

- Display settings list "Unknown"
- Cannot dim screen with control keys
- No drivers listed under Additional Drivers

I have found a few questions related to this graphics card but none of these help me resolved my problem:

- [ATI 6470m & intel HD graphics 3000 drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95459/ati-6470m-intel-hd-graphics-3000-drivers)
- [Intel HD 3000 (Sandy Bridge) 3d games problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/87149/46766)
- https://askubuntu.com/q/114594/46766

Specifically, I just want to be able to control the screen brightness and perhaps adjust the resolution. I see that Intel lists a Linux driver released on 2012/04/23 on their download site: [downloadcenter.intel.com](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Processor%20graphics&ProductProduct=2nd%20Generation%20Intel%C2%AE%20Core%E2%84%A2%20Processors%20with%20Intel%C2%AE%20HD%20Graphics%203000/2000&OSVersion=Linux*). But it recommends "obtaining precompiled driver packages from your Linux distribution vendor".

I'd like to install either though a simple command line command or through the Additional Drivers window under System Settings.

Is this possible in either 11.10 or, if I upgrade, 12.04?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible in either 11.10 or, if I upgrade, 12.04?

Intel HD Graphics 3000 works perfectly on my Lenovo T520; recognized automatically, all resolutions available, Unity (3D) enabled; no need to install any additional drivers (in fact, that option lists nothing in System Settings).

I strongly recommending upgrading to 12.04, because it gives you a newer kernel and a lot of the basic graphics driver functionality is incorporated into the kernel these days.

As for the screen brightness keys, that is *not* a function of the graphics driver but rather ACPI (the mechanism for controlling power); that is also primarily supported through kernel (modules), so upgrading should give you a higher chance of that working too.

Once you upgrade, please post a new question about any little problems that may remain, and we can try to help you out.